# Downloading google maps traffic in shp format?

Tags: shapefile, google-maps, download, traffic

Is it possible to get (download) the info of roads traffic (google maps.com) of an area (in shp format)? If yes, how?

Comment: It is an encrypted raster overlay with transparency but also breaks the terms and conditions if scraped . Use the API to access traffic with Google Maps trafficLayer.setMap(map); https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-traffic

Comment: could you explain this more? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data is an image dynamically created but now encrypted. The answer remains, you cannot download a shapefile from Google Maps.

Comment: @Mapperz Great info! You should post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: No you cannot download this data in any format.

This is passed over as an encrypted raster, and even if you could in some way parse this information, you would be breaking Google Map' terms & conditions by doing so.